# Foreach agrupar valores

Tags: php, html, input, foreach

tenho o seguinte codigo

```
  foreach ($_POST['codmunicipio'] as $key => $valor2) {
      $codmunicipio = $valor2;

       $valor_ipl3_f = $_POST['IPL3_valor_F'];
       $valor_ipl3_j = $_POST['IPL3_valor_J'];

  $sql3 = "INSERT INTO financeiro_sici_anatel_ipl3 (ano, mes, fistel,codmunicipio, IPL3_valor_F, IPL3_valor_J)

  VALUES ('$ano_upload', '$mes_uplooad', '$fistel','$codmunicipio', '$valor_ipl3_f', '$valor_ipl3_j')"; 

  }
```

estou tentando fazer que para cada codigo do municipio ele pegue um valor_f e valor j_

```
        exemplo: codmunicipio 1
     valor_f 20
     valorj_ 30

     codmunicipio 2
     valor_f 10
     valor_j 50
```

etc

e depois inserir numa base de dados.

alguma dica?

essas informaçoes vem da seguinte página:

```
  <?php  

   $id = 1;  

    while($dado_ipl3 = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_ipl3)) { 

      $id++;

     $nome_municipio = $dado_ipl3['CIDADE'];
       $codmunicipio = $dado_ipl3['COD_CIDADE'];








           ?>

         <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $id;?>">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">


      <div class="container">


    <div class="row">       
    <label class="col-md-3">IPL3 Distribuição do quantitativo total de acessos fisícos em serviço por tipo de usuário (mensal)</label>                       
    </div>


     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">Nome Município</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="nome_municipio" id="nome_municipio" class="form-control" value="<?php echo"$nome_municipio" ?>"   maxlength="18" size="18" title="Nome Município">
    </div>                       
    </div> 
    </div>


    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">Codigo Municipio</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="codmunicipio[]" id="codmunicipio" class="form-control numero_livre" value="<?php echo $codmunicipio; ?>"  maxlength="7" size="7">
    </div>                       
    </div> 
  </div>


     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">Acesso físico P.F.</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" name="IPL3_valor_F[]" id="IPL3_valor_F" class="form-control numero" value="0"   maxlength="18" size="18" title="Quantitativo de Acesso físico em serviço pelo tipo da Pessoa Física">
    </div>                       
    </div> 
</div>

     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">        
    <label class="col-md-3">Acesso físico P.J.</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
   <input type="text" name="IPL3_valor_J[]" id="IPL3_valor_J" class="form-control numero" value="0"  maxlength="18" size="18" title="Quantitativo de Acesso físico em serviço pelo tipo da Pessoa Jurídica">
    </div>                       
    </div> 
   </div>


  </div>
   </div>


   <?php   


  }


 ?>
```

Comment: esse `$_POST['codmunicipio']` é um array? Qual é exatamente o problema? Você não está conseguindo inserir?

Comment: O que você quer é inserir de uma vez esses valores?

Comment: Outra coisa.. Esses valores são um array? `$valor_ipl3_f = $_POST['IPL3_valor_F'];
       $valor_ipl3_j = $_POST['IPL3_valor_J'];` ?

Comment: Postei a página de origem dos valores. Estão dentro de uma estrutura While...essa é a minha dificuldade. passar para outra pagina para poder inserir todas informaçoes no banco de dados

Comment: Acho que eu entendi... esses valores são numéricos?

Comment: Isso! todos são números.

Comment: Se tiver um municipio consigo normalmente. mas quando tem varios eu nao consigo passar os valores para outra pagina.

Comment: Entendi... Estou analisando aqui. Vou formular uma resposta.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei o código e nele estou explicando detalhadamente:

```
 // primeira parte da string de inserção
 $sql3 = " INSERT INTO financeiro_sici_anatel_ipl3 (ano, mes, fistel,codmunicipio, IPL3_valor_F, IPL3_valor_J) VALUES ";
 $chave = 0; // chave inicial

 foreach ($_POST['codmunicipio'] as $key => $valor2) {

      $codmunicipio = $valor2;
      $valor_ipl3_f = $_POST['IPL3_valor_F'][$chave]; // pega o valor relacionado ao municipio
      $valor_ipl3_j = $_POST['IPL3_valor_J'][$chave]; // pega o valor relacionado ao municipio
      $sql3 .= "('$ano_upload', '$mes_uplooad', '$fistel','$codmunicipio', '$valor_ipl3_f', '$valor_ipl3_j'),"; // concatena os valores
      $chave++; // adiciona a próxima chave
  }

  $sql3 = substr($sql3, 0, -1); // retira a ultima virgula
```

1. Repare que coloquei a string da query fora do `foreach` para que
   você possa subir as informações de uma vez só. E fui concatenando os valores que serão inseridos. Então, no final, sua string ficará mais ou menos assim:

Exemplo com 2 municípios:

```
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO financeiro_sici_anatel_ipl3 
(ano, mes, fistel,codmunicipio, IPL3_valor_F, IPL3_valor_J) 
VALUES 
('2017', '04', 'fistel1','10', '1', '2'),
('2016', '05', 'fistel2','12', '10', '5')";
```

2. Os valores dos arrays `$valor_ipl3_f` e `$valor_ipl3_j` podem ser acessados de forma numérica. Então cada informação acessada do código do município pelo `foreach`, a próxima informação será uma de cada um desses arrays. Por isso fiz desta forma, usando a variável `$chave`.

Se você tiver mais alguma dúvida ou problema, poste aqui que a gente arruma.

Comment: Muito Obrigado novamente! Consegui inserir no banco de dados!

Comment: @olifreitas que bom! Abraço!